# How to use Lagrange multiplier rule?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I have this function $f (x,y) = x$ with constraints $h_1 (x,y) = -(x+1)^2 -y^2+1 \leq 0$ and $h_2 (x,y)=x^2+y^2 -2 \leq 0$.

With the Lagrange multiplier rule:

$$\lambda_0 \nabla f (x,y) + \mu_1 \nabla h_1 (x,y) + \mu_2 \nabla h_2 (x,y) = 0$$

I get:

$$\lambda_0 + \mu_1 (-2x-2 +2y)+ mu_2 (2x+2y)=0$$

But how should I solve this ?

Thank you !

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @GNUSupporter Everything was set up, it was just that the use of `$$` and the backslash was not there.

Comment: @idk Sorry for crashing your edit.  Due to the backlashes and the dollar signs, I won't say that it's set up.

Comment: @GNUSupporter That's fine. The post has been improved, which is good.

Comment: @idk approved your other edits.  hope you'll become a 2k user soon.

Comment: You don't need Lagrange at all.  Draw a picture and conclude that $x=\sqrt2$, $y=0$ is the maximum.